# WPF Button IsEnabled Bound PropertyChanged Event Not Firing Asynchronously

Tags: wpf, xaml, asynchronous, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a XAML window with a `Button` that has its `IsEnabled` property bound to a boolean property in the window's ViewModel.

XAML:

```
 <Button
 IsEnabled="{Binding SearchButtonEnabled}"
 Command="{Binding Search}"
 Content="Search" />
```

ViewModel:

```
       public bool SearchButtonEnabled
       {


            get
            {
                return _searchButtonEnabled;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_searchButtonEnabled != value)
                {
                    _searchButtonEnabled = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SearchButtonEnabled"));
                }
            }
        }
```

In the ViewModel constructor I am calling an `async` function to populate a `DataGrid`:

```
private async void LoadSearchGrid()
        {
            string sql = "Query that takes a long time";
            SqlCommand gridSourceCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            SearchFilters = new DisplaySearchFilterCollection();

            SearchButtonEnabled = false;
            SearchGridSource = await getDataTableAsync(gridSourceCommand);
            SearchButtonEnabled = true;
        }
```

Now, the code that is giving me issues is the line:

```
SearchButtonEnabled = true;
```

The line the disables the `SearchButtonEnabled` property *always* works, while the line enabling it only sometimes works. If I replace the "Query that takes a long time" with a "Query that takes very little time" the property is enabled just fine and the UI is updated accordingly. Otherwise the button just stays disabled. I have done research on the topic and it is obvious updating the UI can be problematic if done so on a worker thread, but I haven't found a good reason why in this context. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your await is ever finishing? I just wrote a very quick application that simply did a `Thread.Sleep()` (from an async method) and it successfully worked with a 60 second delay.

Comment: @Steve I added a break point to the following line and it did break. I was able to step through the property setter and saw that the property was set to true.

Comment: Try replacing your "long query" with the following code, to simulate a long pause, to see if it might be your query: `public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync() { await Task.Delay(60000); return "Finished"; }` (or something along those lines).

Comment: @Steve This did not work either unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.